# How to create WPF dynamic list of paragraphs?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm using Elysium for creation Metro-like GUI for Windows 7.

I want to create GUI for app with 3 columns with dynamic content with similar animation like its done in many **mobile** apps and some websites with Javascript ("infinite scrolling pages").
So you press refresh button and it adds few new feeds to each column with smooth animation.

I'm trying to move away from idea of using Javascript itself for rendering results but I pretty much don't see any other option.

What kind of controls should I use for that or/and how to implement such effect?

**Update 1:** Looks like its called Pile Board
**Update 2:** Currently looking into ObservableCollection and Elysium.Extras (DataGrid) combo.
Seems like there's also MahApps as alternative to Elysium with Pile control included.

Comment: what did you try? you can animate text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754028(v=vs.110).aspx. you can move images (scroll images and text), fade out...

Comment: Unfortunately it's only useful if I want to add it to bottom, while I want to add it to top. Use of list-like structure is needed so it's possible to implement hide/star buttons for individial feeds and such.